# Instrumentation Tools for C?

Tags: c

Suggestions needed for best instrumentation tools for a C project. I actually like to know when control was transferred from a function to another function and therefore I want to do something like instrumenting printf commands at the end and start of each function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use GCC as a compiler, it has a `-finstrument-functions` option that automatically generates calls on entering and leaving functions.
This allows customization of what you try to instrument.

Answer (score 3):

The `valgrind` tool has all sorts of hooks you can program that would let you watch this happen.  In particular, [the `callgrind` tool](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/cl-manual.html) might be appropriate here.

Comment: thanks a lot for helping :) I will try valgrind some day hopefully.